# Rescaling with plyr (ddply) in R

Tags: r, plyr

I've got this csv table for which I need to rescale data between 0 and 1 per each column. That is, the lowest value of any given column will be 0, the highest will be 1, and all other values will be linearly scaled accordingly. Here's my script:

```
tableau  <- read.csv("/tableau.csv")
tableau.m <- melt(tableau)
tableau.m <- ddply(tableau.m, .(variable), transform,rescale = rescale(value))
```

(And here's the data: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/tableau.csv)

The issue is that I need the second column ("B") to be inverted. That is, for this column only and not for the others, the lowest value should be 1, and the highest should be 0.

Is *plyr* flexible that way, or should I try other ways to achieve this?

[image]

(In this example, column B should read with 2.13 being white, 1.88 being dark blue, and 2.07's, 2.09's, 2.05's shades being scaled accordingly. The other column should be left untouched.)

Comment: Have you tried `ddply(tableau.m, .(variable), transform,rescale = rescale(-value))` (not tested)

Comment: library(scales); rescale(values, to = c(1,0))

Comment: That would work, but I need only the first column to be inverted.

Comment: Your first column is 'Net'.  Could you show the expected output for a small example

Comment: Oh sorry, the second column indeed. I'll correct my question... Thanks!

Comment: Would `sapply`ing through `tableau` and inverting the first column work?

Comment: Try order `tableau$B <- tableau$B[order(-tableau$B)]` and then `rescale` perhaps?

Comment: Hi! Akrun, this doesn't work as it moves the values around. I still need the values to be properly placed to be displayed in the plot.
@Roman Luštrik, I'm not familiar with sapply, would you have an example of how it could be used in my case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `ifelse` to select the scaling direction, based on the value of `variable`:

```
tableau.m = ddply(tableau.m, .(variable), transform,
                  rescale = ifelse(variable=="B", 
                                   rescale(value, to=c(1,0)), rescale(value)))

   Net variable value    rescale
1    a        B  1.88 1.00000000
2    b        B  2.05 0.32000000
3    c        B  2.09 0.16000000
4    d        B  2.07 0.24000000
5    e        B  2.13 0.00000000
6    a        C  0.15 0.00000000
7    b        C  0.23 0.21621622
8    c        C  0.29 0.37837838
9    d        C  0.52 1.00000000
10   e        C  0.30 0.40540541
11   a        D  0.60 1.00000000
12   b        D  0.51 0.72727273
13   c        D  0.40 0.39393939
14   d        D  0.36 0.27272727
15   e        D  0.27 0.00000000
16   a    E..e. 10.00 0.04109589
17   b    E..e. 55.00 0.65753425
18   c    E..e. 58.00 0.69863014
19   d    E..e. 80.00 1.00000000
20   e    E..e.  7.00 0.00000000
21   a    F..f. 90.00 1.00000000
22   b    F..f. 80.00 0.00000000
23   c    F..f. 88.00 0.80000000
24   d    F..f. 84.00 0.40000000
25   e    F..f. 90.00 1.00000000
```

Comment: Rodolphe, see my updated answer. My original answer was incorrect, because simply reversing the scaling direction also reverses the relative distances between values, which will give incorrect color shadings. The new version (which is similar to @Henk's suggestion, but applied by column, instead of to the whole data frame) preserves relative distances.