# Geom_tile using a scale fill gradient within each level rather than entire data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am recently exploring R and I am trying to do a geom_tile plot in ggplot where rather than set up the scale of high to low between all range of values, a comparison is made at each level of a variable for 4 factor levels.

An example of the data is:

```
data <- read.table(text = "

cam k1  k2  k3
n1  342232.6    112964      56589.85
n2  159472.8    54713.9     29480.88
n3  102048.4    38358.95    23376.48
n4  75924.33    32455.58    22504.05

", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

I have written this simple code to get a colour map that uses the entire range of values.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

datam <- melt(data)

p <- ggplot(datam, aes(cam,variable)) 

(p + geom_tile(aes(fill=value), colour = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="green",high="red"))
```

**However, I would like to get a gradient fill scale that compares the range of values (i.e. 4 values) between factors *cam* but within each level of *k*.  Basically to highlight the lowest value at each level of *k*.***

I have many scenarios to plot, so a facet for each level of k is not an option.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.    Thanks

Comment: Transform your data (using dplyr or data.table) so it matches what you want to plot, then plot it.

Comment: Scale each set of values to be between 0-1 and then just use a single fill scale.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040420/heat-map-per-column-with-ggplot2/30040582#30040582) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078074/rescaling-with-plyr-ddply-in-r) might be of help.

Comment: thanks!  previous posts worked.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heat map per column with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040420/heat-map-per-column-with-ggplot2)